# Delete missing database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

[image]Event Viewer, I can fins this event logged :

> 2016-07-10 11:45:01.83 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38. 
>   2016-07-10 11:45:01.83 Logon       Login failed for user 'Domain\Username'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified
>   database. [CLIENT: ]

So,I ran trace and found the database name,but how can I delete the missing database completely. Attached image.

I cannot find the database name in sp_helpdb or sys.databases.

> Cannot open database "DBTest" requested by the login. The login
>   failed.

Comment: You dont need to delete already deleted database. You need to see login properties and check whether default database it connects to is not the DBtest

Comment: @Shanky,default database name is master.I checked in sys.server_princiapls

Comment: In that case there is some application trying to connect to the database DBtest using that login and you need to find that

Comment: also see this link which has all the login failures info: https://sqlblog.org/2020/07/28/troubleshooting-error-18456

Comment: @Shanky,I have attached the image of the trace.Can you please let me know how to proceed further.I know application,database name,login name now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t need to delete the already missing database.The user is configured to use a none existing or deleted database as a default database for the application. First, use trace and check for which application the user is failed to login, then on the application, change the default database to one of the existing databases. Sadequl’s post  might help you for step by step guide to fix the issue, https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2581/sql-server-error-18456-finding-the-missing-databases/

Comment: I can see Application name is .Net SQLClient Data Provider  from the trace file.

Comment: A .Net SQLClient Data Provider actually is not the application name. You are seeing that on the trace because the application name is not specifically configured on the connection string. Now you might have to do one additional step. Set a trace &check all the statements and SP’s executed when that specific error occur, which will lead you which application using that. First, make sure the 'Domain\Username’ has appropriate permission and its default database should be one of the existing database. This will easily fix your issue.

Comment: I tried adding the database back and run the trace still the issue exists

Comment: You don’t necessarily have to create the database, you have to just check the failed user and your application and change the default to one of the existing databases. If you follow all the steps on this link, https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2581/sql-server-error-18456-finding-the-missing-databases/, you can easily fix the issue.